# Get the value from unique appended selector using Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that spawn a selector and a div, both with unique IDs. I'm trying to get the value from one of these unique appended selectors with a JQuery function. So far I can get the value from the selector option and show in the div, but it shows in every other div that was spawned. I want to show only in the div related to the selector.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#createNewLayer', function () {
      $('#mainSeparator').append(
        '<div id="newLayer" class="newLayer"> <div class="form-row"> <div class="form-group col-md-6"> <select class="form-control mySelector" id="selector"> <option hidden disabled selected value>Select an option</option> <option>1</option> <option>2</option> <option>3</option><option>4</option> </select> </div></div><div class="newDiv"></div></div>'
      );
});

$(document).on('change', '.mySelector', function () {
  var str = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get().join('');
  $('.newDiv').text(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainSeparator">
  <div id="newLayer" class="newLayer">        
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control mySelector" id="selector">
          <option hidden disabled selected value>Select an option</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newDiv"></div>
  </div>      
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="createNewLayer" style="margin-top: 20px;">New Layer</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch `$('.newDiv').text(str)` with `$(this).closest('.newLayer').find('.newDiv').text(str);`

Problem is that you are not targeting a specific `$('.newDiv')` but all of them.

**Working demo**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#createNewLayer', function() {
  $('#mainSeparator').append(
    '<div id="newLayer" class="newLayer"> <div class="form-row"> <div class="form-group col-md-6"> <select class="form-control mySelector" id="selector"> <option hidden disabled selected value>Select an option</option> <option>1</option> <option>2</option> <option>3</option><option>4</option> </select> </div></div><div class="newDiv"></div></div>'
  );
});

$(document).on('change', '.mySelector', function() {
  var str = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get().join('');
  $(this).closest('.newLayer').find('.newDiv').text(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainSeparator">
  <div id="newLayer" class="newLayer">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control mySelector" id="selector">
          <option hidden disabled selected value>Select an option</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="newDiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="createNewLayer" style="margin-top: 20px;">New Layer</button>
```

Comment: I figured what I should do, but I had no idea how. Thank you very much!